# Not able to cast str to int in a python list

Tags: python, list, casting

I want to cast elements in a list (string to integer)
Can't find what my mistake is. I just get strings.
Some other post answers suggest list comprehensions, but, being a newbie, I prefer understanding why this more basic approach doesn't work, before learning list comprehensions.

Thanks for your help.

(Using Python 3)

I tried:

```
while True:
    userInput=input("Write space-separated numbers:  ")
    listNumbers=userInput.split()
    for i in listNumbers:
        int(i)
    print(type(listNumbers[0]))
```

Also tried:

```
for i in listNumbers:
    i=int(i)
```

I expect the type(listNumbers[0]) or whatever index number to return integer
but the output is still a string.

Comment: you're not changing the items in listnumbers, just iterating through it changing i each time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must do:

```
for i in range(0, len(listNumbers)):
    listNumbers[i] = int(listNumbers[i])
```

or:

```
for idx, val in enumerate(listNumbers):
    listNumbers[idx] = value
```

This can be shortened using:

```
listNumbers = [int(x) for x in listNumbers]
```

When doing:

```
for i in listNumbers):
    i = int(i)
```

`i` is only a reference to the elements so you can't change the original value of the list.

When doing:

```
for i in listNumbers:
    int(i)
```

You don't store the result of `int(i)`.

Comment: I understood that I did nothing with the int(i) alone, but with i=int(i), it's more difficult to understand to me, because it seems it's the natural way of casting and keeping the int property like memorized in the i variable. I'll work with the elements index, as proposed.

Bedankt!

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from the fact that you do not store the integer in the loop !

Do :

```
mylist = []
for i in listNumbers:
    mylist.append(int(i))
```

The best solution is

```
listNumbers = list(map(int, listNumbers))
```

Comment: Liked that, because probably it's the shortest way, and still using the for loop.
Merci!

Answer (score 1):

`int(i)` does not convert the element `i` in the list to an integer, you would need to explicitly assign `int(i)` back to the element in the list for that to happen

```
while True:

    userInput=input("Write space-separated numbers:  ")
    listNumbers=userInput.split()

    #Iterate over the list and get index and element of list
    for idx, i in enumerate(listNumbers):
        #Cast string to int and assign back to list
        listNumbers[idx] = int(i)

    #Get the type
    print(type(listNumbers[0]))
```

The output will be

```
Write space-separated numbers:  1 3 5
<class 'int'>
```

Comment: Well explained. Thanks!

Comment: No worries @lljorgero If the answer helped you, please consider upvoting the answer :)

Comment: I did, but still doesn't count because I don't have 15 rep. points yet.

Answer (score 1):

you need to actually save your modified value back into the list

```
for i,val in enumerate(my_list):
    my_list[i] = int(val)
```

but as mentioned its much better to just use a list comprehension

```
new_list = [int(val) for val in my_list]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first variant doesn't do anything, because the cast value is just thrown away.

Your second variant does assign the value to `i`, but that doesn't change the value that is stored in the list.

I suggest using a list comprehension instead:

```
while True:
    userInput=input("Write space-separated numbers:  ")
    listNumbers=[int(i) for i in userInput.split()]
    print(type(listNumbers[0]))
```